# Rust Builder pattern derive-macro

Tags: beginner, rust, macros

Inspired by dtolnay's procedural macro workshop (on [Github](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro-workshop)), I have implemented a derive-macro to automatically implement the Builder pattern on a Rust struct, which allows a struct instance to be created using chained method calls on an intermediate object instead of having to provide all the required values at once. A more exact specification (along with a usage example) is given in the top-level doc comment in `lib.rs`.

This is my first "real" Rust project, so I'd be especially interested to hear about more idiomatic ways to approach this problem.

**lib.rs**

````
extern crate proc_macro;
mod fields;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use proc_macro2::{self, Ident, Span};
use quote::{format_ident, quote};
use syn::{parse_macro_input, Data, DeriveInput, Field, Fields};

use fields::{AnalyzedField, MetaData};

/// Constructs an implementation of the builder pattern for the struct.
///
/// Generates a struct `{struct_name}Builder` that can be created using
/// the `builder()` method on the main struct.
///
/// Initialize fields of the builder using methods of the same name as
/// the fields. These can also be chained.
///
/// All fields must be set (see exceptions below) before the `build()` method
/// may be called, which will return an instance of the struct with the
/// values from the builder. If `build()` is called before all values have been set,
/// an `Incomplete{struct_name}Error` will be returned.
///
/// Fields of the form `Option<T>` in the struct do not have to be set before
/// calling `build()`.
///
/// Fields of the form `Vec<T>` can be annotated with `#[builder(each = "{arg}")]`
/// to generate a method `arg(T)` that will append its argument to the Vec.
/// A Vec that is annotated with `each` will be initialized to an empty Vec on
/// construction of the builder.
///
/// # Example
///
/// ```
/// use derive_builder::Builder;
///
/// #[derive(Builder)]
/// struct Thing {
///     num: usize,
///     name: String,
///     optional: Option<String>,
///     #[builder(each = "arg")]
///     args: Vec<i32>,
/// }
///
/// let instance = Thing::builder()
///                 .num(25)
///                 .name("John".to_owned())
///                 .arg(5)
///                 .arg(34)
///                 .build()
///                 .unwrap();
///
/// assert_eq!(instance.num, 25);
/// assert_eq!(instance.name, "John".to_owned());
/// assert_eq!(instance.optional, None);
/// assert_eq!(instance.args, vec![5, 34]);
/// ```
#[proc_macro_derive(Builder, attributes(builder))]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    let name = &input.ident;

    let fields = match input.data {
        Data::Struct(syn::DataStruct {
            fields: Fields::Named(fields),
            ..
        }) => fields.named.into_iter().collect::<Vec<Field>>(),
        _ => {
            let e = syn::Error::new_spanned(
                &input,
                "the builder macro may only be used with named fields",
            )
            .to_compile_error();
            return TokenStream::from(quote! {
                fn err() { #e }
            });
        }
    };

    let mut analyzed_fields: Vec<AnalyzedField> = Vec::with_capacity(fields.len());
    for field in fields {
        match AnalyzedField::new(field) {
            Ok(f) => analyzed_fields.push(f),
            Err(e) => {
                let e = e.to_compile_error();
                return TokenStream::from(quote! {
                    fn err() { #e }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    let builder_constructor = make_builder_constructor(name, &analyzed_fields);

    let builder_struct = make_builder_struct(name, &analyzed_fields);

    let builder_impl = make_builder_impl(name, &analyzed_fields);

    let error_type = make_builder_error_type(name);

    let tokens = TokenStream::from(quote! {
        #builder_constructor
        #builder_struct
        #builder_impl
        #error_type
    });

    tokens
}

fn make_builder_constructor(
    type_name: &proc_macro2::Ident,
    fields: &Vec<AnalyzedField>,
) -> proc_macro2::TokenStream {
    let builder_initializers = fields.iter().map(|field| {
        let ident = field.get_field().ident.as_ref().unwrap();
        match field.get_meta_data() {
            MetaData::Each(_, _) => quote! { #ident: std::option::Option::Some(Vec::new()) },
            _ => quote! { #ident: std::option::Option::None },
        }
    });

    let name_builder = get_builder_name(type_name);

    quote! {
        impl #type_name {
            pub fn builder() -> #name_builder {
                #name_builder {
                    #(#builder_initializers),*
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn make_builder_struct(
    type_name: &proc_macro2::Ident,
    fields: &Vec<AnalyzedField>,
) -> proc_macro2::TokenStream {
    let option_fields = fields.iter().map(|field| {
        let ident = field.get_field().ident.as_ref().unwrap();
        let ty = field.get_setter_arg_type();
        quote! { #ident: std::option::Option<#ty>}
    });

    let name_builder = get_builder_name(type_name);

    quote! {
        pub struct #name_builder {
            #(#option_fields),*
        }
    }
}

fn make_builder_error_type(type_name: &proc_macro2::Ident) -> proc_macro2::TokenStream {
    let error_type_name = get_error_type_name(type_name);

    quote! {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        pub struct #error_type_name {
            missing_field: &'static str,
        }

        impl std::fmt::Display for #error_type_name {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
                write!(f, "Field {} is missing from builder.", self.missing_field)
            }
        }

        impl std::error::Error for #error_type_name {}
    }
}

fn make_builder_impl(
    type_name: &proc_macro2::Ident,
    fields: &Vec<AnalyzedField>,
) -> proc_macro2::TokenStream {
    let methods = make_builder_methods(fields);
    let error_type_name = get_error_type_name(type_name);
    let name_builder = get_builder_name(type_name);

    let checks = fields.iter().map(|field| {
        let ident = field.get_field().ident.as_ref().unwrap();
        match field.get_meta_data() {
            MetaData::Optional(_) => {
                quote! {
                    let #ident = self.#ident.take();
                }
            }
            _ => {
                let field_name = ident.to_string();
                quote! {
                    let #ident = self.#ident.take()
                        .ok_or(#error_type_name { missing_field: #field_name })?;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    let setters = fields.iter().map(|field| {
        let ident = field.get_field().ident.as_ref().unwrap();
        quote! {
            #ident
        }
    });

    quote! {
        impl #name_builder {
            #(#methods)*

            pub fn build(&mut self) -> std::result::Result<#type_name, #error_type_name> {
                #(#checks)*
                Ok(#type_name {
                    #(#setters),*
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

fn make_builder_methods(fields: &Vec<AnalyzedField>) -> Vec<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {
    fields
        .iter()
        .map(|field| {
            let ident = field.get_field().ident.as_ref().unwrap();
            let ty = field.get_setter_arg_type();
            let mut setter = quote! {
                pub fn #ident(&mut self, #ident: #ty) -> &mut Self {
                    self.#ident = std::option::Option::Some(#ident);
                    self
                }
            };
            let mut appender = proc_macro2::TokenStream::new();
            match field.get_meta_data() {
                MetaData::Each(ref s, ref t) => {
                    let appender_ident = Ident::new(s, Span::call_site());
                    if &ident.to_string() == s {
                        setter = proc_macro2::TokenStream::new();
                    }
                    appender = quote! {
                        pub fn #appender_ident(&mut self, #appender_ident: #t) -> &mut Self {
                            self.#ident.as_mut().unwrap().push(#appender_ident);
                            self
                        }
                    };
                }
                _ => (),
            };
            quote! {
                #setter
                #appender
            }
        })
        .collect()
}

fn get_builder_name(type_name: &proc_macro2::Ident) -> proc_macro2::Ident {
    format_ident!("{}Builder", type_name)
}

fn get_error_type_name(type_name: &proc_macro2::Ident) -> proc_macro2::Ident {
    format_ident!("Incomplete{}Error", type_name)
}
````

**fields.rs**

```
use proc_macro2::{self, Ident};
use syn::Field;

/// A struct field that has been analyzed for
/// properties of interest to the Builder macro.
/// The results of the analysis are given as [`MetaData`].
pub struct AnalyzedField {
    field: Field,
    meta: MetaData,
}

/// Holds additional information on fields to be initialized
/// in the builder.
pub enum MetaData {
    /// A field with no special treatment
    Normal,
    /// A field that is an [Option<T>] in the final struct
    /// and is thus not obligatory to set in the builder.
    /// The contained type is the `T` from the Option.
    Optional(syn::Type),
    /// A field that is a [Vec<T>] in the struct
    /// and can be appended to in the builder using the method
    /// with the name in the string.
    /// The contained type is the `T` from the Vec.
    Each(String, syn::Type),
}

const EACH_KEYWORD: &str = "each";
const ATTR_PATH: &str = "builder";
const EACH_REQ_TYPE: &str = "Vec";
const OPTIONAL_TYPE: &str = "Option";

impl AnalyzedField {

    /// Analyzes the field and initializes the attached metadata.
    /// Returns an error if one occured while parsing a builder attribute
    /// or if there was a type mismatch between attribute requirements
    /// and the given types in the struct (e.g. "each" requires a [Vec<T>]).
    pub fn new(field: Field) -> Result<Self, syn::Error> {
        let builder_attr = Self::get_builder_attr(&field);
        if let Some(attr) = builder_attr {
            let appender_name = Self::parse_each_attribute(attr)?;
            match Self::get_generic_type(&field, EACH_REQ_TYPE) {
                Some(t) => Ok(Self {
                    field,
                    meta: MetaData::Each(appender_name, t),
                }),
                None => Err(syn::Error::new_spanned(
                    field,
                    format!("`{}` requires type {}<T>", EACH_KEYWORD, EACH_REQ_TYPE),
                )),
            }
        } else if let Some(t) = Self::get_generic_type(&field, OPTIONAL_TYPE) {
            Ok(Self {
                field,
                meta: MetaData::Optional(t),
            })
        } else {
            Ok(Self {
                field,
                meta: MetaData::Normal,
            })
        }
    }

    /// Returns the field this instance was initialized with.
    pub fn get_field(&self) -> &Field {
        &self.field
    }

    /// Returns the meta data associated with the field.
    pub fn get_meta_data(&self) -> &MetaData {
        &self.meta
    }

    /// If the field's type is of the form ty<T>, returns Some(T).
    fn get_generic_type(field: &Field, ty: &str) -> Option<syn::Type> {
        if let &syn::Type::Path(syn::TypePath {
            qself: None,
            ref path,
        }) = &field.ty
        {
            if path.segments.len() != 1 {
                return None;
            }

            let segment = path.segments.first().unwrap();
            if segment.ident.to_string() != ty.to_owned() {
                return None;
            }

            match segment.arguments {
                syn::PathArguments::AngleBracketed(ref args) => {
                    Self::extract_generic_argument(args)
                }
                _ => None,
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    /// If there is exactly one generic arguments, returns it.
    fn extract_generic_argument(args: &syn::AngleBracketedGenericArguments) -> Option<syn::Type> {
        if args.args.len() == 1 {
            match args.args.first().unwrap() {
                syn::GenericArgument::Type(ref t) => Some(t.clone()),
                _ => None,
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    /// Returns an attribute of the form #[builder(...)] if one exists on the field.
    fn get_builder_attr(field: &Field) -> Option<&syn::Attribute> {
        field
            .attrs
            .iter()
            .find(|attr| attr.path.get_ident().map(Ident::to_string) == Some(ATTR_PATH.to_owned()))
    }

    /// Parses an attribute of the form #[builder(each = "...")] and returns
    /// the literal string argument. Returns an error if the attribute cannot
    /// be parsed in this manner.
    fn parse_each_attribute(attr: &syn::Attribute) -> Result<String, syn::Error> {
        let meta = attr.parse_meta()?;

        let error = Err(syn::Error::new_spanned(
            &meta,
            format!("expected `{}({} = \"...\")`", ATTR_PATH, EACH_KEYWORD),
        ));

        let args = if let syn::Meta::List(ref list) = meta {
            &list.nested
        } else {
            return error;
        };

        if args.len() != 1 {
            return error;
        }

        if let Some(&syn::NestedMeta::Meta(syn::Meta::NameValue(ref name))) = args.first() {
            if name.path.get_ident().map(Ident::to_string) == Some(EACH_KEYWORD.to_owned()) {
                match &name.lit {
                    &syn::Lit::Str(ref lit_str) => return Ok(lit_str.value()),
                    _ => return error,
                }
            } else {
                return error;
            }
        } else {
            return error;
        }
    }

    /// Gets the type that should be used by a setter in the builder.
    pub fn get_setter_arg_type(&self) -> &syn::Type {
        match &self.meta {
            &MetaData::Optional(ref t) => t,
            _ => &self.field.ty,
        }
    }
}
```